# write private file to internal storage

Tags: android, file, private, data-storage

I trying to write some files on the internal storage.

I saw the`FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` on [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) and I understood that the file will be private to my application.

but the problem is it can only open a file without a path, so first I opened a new directory file with file.mkdir(), but now, how do I write the file as private ?

Comment: so why you are not try to store in sdcard?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I saw theFileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); on Data Storage and I understood that the file will be private to my application.

Correct. They will be private by default.

> but the problem is it can only open a file without a path, so first I opened a new directory file with file.mkdir(), but now, how do I write the file as private ?

Your files that you create in subdirectories off of in `getFilesDir()` are private by default -- you do not have to do anything special to make them be private.

Comment: But as per the android training documentation (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage)

Answer (score 1):

If you call Context.openFileOutput() the file will always be written into your application's data directory (i.e. "/data/data/appname/filename"). You cannot use sub folders here!
[The documentation for this function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) says

> nameThe name of the file to open; can not contain path separators.

Comment: yes, I know this. but @CommonsWare said every directory I create in my app's data directory will be private.

so I created a folder using new File("/data/data/appname/dirname").mkdir()