# Writing file to internal storage

Tags: java, android

I want to write or place my file in Android Internal storage and I am doing this -

```
try {
    File file = new File("/data/local/measurement.txt");

    // if file doesnt exists, then create it
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(content.toString());
    bw.close();

    Log.d("hi", "WRITTEN");

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I already have measurement.txt in /data/local path but nothing is being written to it. I am using emulator and I have also given permissions like

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Not your issue but you know you can just do `new FileWriter(file)`. Anyways are you sure `content.toString()` is returning a non-empty string? Log its value to confirm.

Comment: Yea content is an Arraylist with some object data in it

Comment: Is your log message appearing?

Comment: No it is not coming... I am getting log as java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/local/measurements.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: You may need to open the file output stream: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: @FAZ Well you should include that detail in your post. In any case check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467161/creating-and-writing-to-a-file-on-internal-storage?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773497/write-private-file-to-internal-storage?rq=1 and use `Context.openFileOutput`, the file should be in your package data folder not `/data/local`.

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("myfile", MODE_PRIVATE)));
out.write(string);
out.close();
```

This will put the file in `/data/data/<pkg>/files`, private to your app, where it belongs. You don't need any permissions for this.